# How can I delay a change to my model until I finish typing?

Tags: angularjs

I have this field:

```
 <input ng-model="phs.englishRange"
                   style="width:6rem;"
                   type="text" />
```

The word is used in a filter so when I make any changes to it the filter changes while the changes are being made.  Is there a way I can delay this to the model changes 1 second after I stop typing?

Comment: Are you using `$watcher`?

Comment: No, I don't know about $watcher.  The model value is used in a ng-repeat filter:  ng-repeat="row in phs.phrasesView = (phs.phrases | keywordRange:phs.englishRange )"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For your use-case**, to trigger model update 1s after last character typed (model update timer will be reset each time):

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default', debounce: {'default': 1000} }"
```

**More options - update on blur:**

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

Options are "default" (as you type) and/or "blur" (when you leave the input).

You can also use `debounce` inside model-options to control how fast to issue the model update.

```
debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 }
```

Comment: Does that not only work when I move the cursor to some other field?

Comment: Yes, you can use debounce: {'default': 1000} for that